# 2012 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

IT Security's [second moderator election](https://security.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Jeff Ferland]

He'll be joining [the existing crew](https://security.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) shortly — please thank him for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice as he learns the ropes!

Comment: @JeffFerland, congratulations!

Comment: Thank you! I'm excited to help keep our community running!

Comment: Who's got two thumbs and is about to wade knee-deep into troll maintenance? This guy!

Comment: Wow, they did a fast turnaround on getting you that diamond @JeffFerland! Congrats. :)

Comment: That is nice, but out of topic because this is only for asking questions. You need to visit the [Help center](http://security.stackexchange.com/help) for more information.